# Can't run Flutter's project on iPhone 9 - Invalid parameter not satisfying: !stayUp || CLClientIsBackgroundable

Tags: iphone, flutter

Android Studio 4 + Flutter project

Success launch my flutter's project on Android device.

Nice. But on iPhone device I get error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreLocationFramework/CoreLocation-1861.3.25.50/Framework/CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.m:609
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: !stayUp || CLClientIsBackgroundable(internal->fClient)'
    *** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Does this issue help? https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/336

Comment: @Benjamin Not help. Now I get error:ssertion failure in -[CLLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:],